# Add a new column in dataframe with user defined values. (pyspark)

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Three values of array A1 getting from some function -

```
A1 = [1,2,3,4]
A1 = [5,6,7,8]
A1 = [1,3,4,1]
```

My dataframe in which I want to add a new column with my array values -

```
+---+---+-----+
| x1| x2|   x3|
+---+---+-----+
|  1|  A|  3.0|
|  2|  B|-23.0|
|  3|  C| -4.0|
+---+---+-----+
```

I tried like this(Suppose 'df' is my dataframe) -

```
for i  in range(0, 2):
   df = df.withColumn("x4", array(lit(A1[0]), lit(A1[1]), lit(A1[2]))
```

But problem with this code is it is updating column with last value of array 'A1' like this -

```
+---+---+-----+---------+
| x1| x2|   x3|       x4|
+---+---+-----+---------+
|  1|  A|  3.0|[1,3,4,1]|
|  2|  B|-23.0|[1,3,4,1]|
|  3|  C| -4.0|[1,3,4,1]|
+---+---+-----+---------+
```

But I want like this -

```
+---+---+-----+---------+
| x1| x2|   x3|       x4|
+---+---+-----+---------+
|  1|  A|  3.0|[1,2,3,4]|
|  2|  B|-23.0|[5,6,7,8]|
|  3|  C| -4.0|[1,3,4,1]|
+---+---+-----+---------+
```

What i need to add extra in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after breaking my head alot, I found that this can not be done using withColumn function of pyspark as it will create a column but all of same row. And also I can not use `udf` because my new column does not depend on any previous column of existing dataframe.

So I did something like this - 
Suppose you are getting different values of array A1 inside a for loop(In my case this is the scenario)

```
f_array = []
for i in range(0,10):
   f_array.extend([(i, A1)])

# Creating a new df for my array.

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data = f_array, schema = ["id", "x4"])
df1.show()

+---+---------+
| id|       x4|
+---+---------+
|  0|[1,2,3,4]|
|  1|[5,6,7,8]|
|  2|[1,3,4,1]|
+---+---------+
# Suppose no columns matches to our df then creating one extra column named `id` as present in our `df1`. This is used for joining both the dataframes.

df = df.withColumn('id', monotonically_increasing_id())
df.show()

+---+---+---+-----+
| id| x1| x2|   x3|
+---+---+---+-----+
|  0|  1|  A|  3.0|
|  1|  2|  B|-23.0|
|  2|  3|  C| -4.0|
+---+---+---+-----+

# Now join both the dataframes using common column `id`.

df = df.join(df1, df.id == df1.id).drop(df.id).drop(df1.id)
df.show()

+---+---+---+------------+
| x1| x2| x3|          x4|
+---+---+---+------------+
|  1|  A|  3|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
|  2|  B|-23|[5, 6, 7, 8]|
|  3|  C| -4|[1, 3, 4, 1]|
+---+---+---+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
df=spark.createDataFrame(data=[(1,'A',3),(2,'B',-23),(3,'C',-4)],schema=['x1','x2','x3'])

+---+---+---+
| x1| x2| x3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  A|  3|
|  2|  B|-23|
|  3|  C| -4|
+---+---+---+

mydict = {1:[1,2,3,4] , 2:[5,6,7,8], 3:[1,3,4,1]}

def addExtraColumn(df,mydict):
    names = df.schema.names
    count=1
    mylst=[]
    for row in df.rdd.collect():
        RW=row.asDict()
        rowLst=[]
        for name in names:
            rowLst.append(RW[name])
        rowLst.append(mydict[count])
        count=count+1
        mylst.append(rowLst)
    return mylst

newlst = addExtraColumn(df,mydict)

df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(newlst).toDF(['x1','x2','x3','x4'])

df1.show()

+---+---+---+------------+
| x1| x2| x3|          x4|
+---+---+---+------------+
|  1|  A|  3|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
|  2|  B|-23|[5, 6, 7, 8]|
|  3|  C| -4|[1, 3, 4, 1]|
+---+---+---+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your previous answer seems more suitable to me as I don't want to use Pandas. I am posting my answer too. Let it be if somebody wants to do the same by using Pandas then your answer can help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, i think A1 value depends on at least one of the columns x1, x2 or x3.

Therefore, you cannot define your new columns with A1, but with a function that will take as parameters the columns you need to define A1.

It is just a supposition but maybe, you just need a dictionnary, `A = {1:[1,2,3,4] , 2:[5,6,7,8], 3:[1,3,4,1],}`and use it in an UDF with your `withColumn`.

Comment: No A1 value does not depend on any columns x1,x2 or x3.

Comment: A1 depends on something. why you want 3 differents values then ? I think you simplified too much your problem because you believe it is too complicated for us ... but now, we do not understand anything.

Comment: Sir A1 list I am creating by counting some no of words. It does not depend on dataframe. If it depends on dataframe then adding that column is much easier and I don't have to ask here so many examples are there itself in stackoverflow.

Comment: What is the rule you use to add you A1 ? if there is no rule, we cannot help. Do you understand that dataframe are not ordered ?